# how can I my installed app in dropdown of odoo12

Tags: xml, drop-down-menu, module, installation, odoo-12

i am new in odoo, as a tutorial odoo12, i have created openacademy module with courses and sessions and install it successfully but i can not see this module on dropdownlist of odoo

I have installed sale module and then i can see the name of "sale" model in dropdown list of odoo but when I create and install openacademy module i can not see it on there

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="course_list_action">
        <field name="name">Courses</field>

        <field name="res_model">openacademy.course</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_smiling_face">Create the first course
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>


    <menuitem id="main_openacademy_menu" name="Open Academy"/>


    <menuitem id="openacademy_menu" name="Open Academy"
              parent="main_openacademy_menu"/>

    <menuitem id="courses_menu" name="Courses" parent="openacademy_menu"
        action="openacademy.course_list_action"
```

i want to see "openacademy" in droplistmenue in odoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is all about access right. the access right of user must have full access to all OpenAcademy model
1-in "the **manifest**.py" add 'security/security.xml' in "date"
2-in "openacademy/security/ir.model.access.csv" edit via "id,name,model_id/id,group_id/id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
course_manager,course manager,model_openacademy_course,group_manager,1,1,1,1
session_manager,session manager,model_openacademy_session,group_manager,1,1,1,1
course_read_all,course all,model_openacademy_course,,1,0,0,0
session_read_all,session all,model_openacademy_session,,1,0,0,0"
3-create "openacademy/security/security.xml" with this content: "

```
    <record id="group_manager" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">OpenAcademy / Manager</field>
    </record>
```

"